# Get on-going and upcoming (order) DateTimes from a List<DateTime> within a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime

Assume I've got a list like this:

```
List<Timer> bosses = new List<Timer>();
bosses.Add(new Timer { Boss = "Tequatl", Priority = BossPriority.HardCore, SpawnTimes =  {  
    DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),  
    DateTime.ParseExact("11:30 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("16:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("19:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("00:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("03:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
}, Runtime = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0) });
bosses.Add(new Timer { Boss = "The Shatterer", Priority = BossPriority.Standard, SpawnTimes = {
    DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("10:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("13:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("16:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("19:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("22:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("01:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("04:00 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
}, Runtime = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0) });
bosses.Add(new Timer { Boss = "Jungle Wurm", Priority = BossPriority.LowLevel, SpawnTimes = {
    DateTime.ParseExact("07:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("09:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("11:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("13:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("15:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("17:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("19:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("21:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("23:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("01:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("03:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateTime.ParseExact("05:15 +0000", "HH:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
}, Runtime = new TimeSpan(0,30, 0) });
```

Each individual datetime is the time of day, so above should be accounted for every day.

From this I need to find what DateTimes (with the associated Boss Class), are currently running, every Timer object has a Runtime, which specifies how long it's running for. For example, my first DateTime starts at 7:00 UTC and ends at 7:30 UTC.

How would I go about this? I was hoping to do this with LINQ but I have no idea on how to order the items so that the datetimes are in chronological order.

I was thinking of maybe "flattening" the whole list, and create a new one, like so:

```
List<BossDatetime> orderedList = new List<BossDatetime>();
foreach (Timer boss in bosses)
{
    foreach (DateTime item in boss.SpawnTimes)
    {
        orderedList.Add(new BossDatetime { Timer = boss, SpawnTime = item });
    }
}
orderedList = orderedList.OrderBy(x => x.SpawnTime).ToList();
```

This seems like a bad practice and also raises some new issues, for example the list is telling me that the closes Datetime is the last:
[image]

To summarize what I'm asking:

1. How can I order my `bosses` list by the DateTime closes me with a reference to the timer, so I know what boss it is regarding, preferably via LINQ
2. How to retrieve the items that are on-going from above list.

Comment: Are these times already ordered?  I notice you have times that appear to cross midnight.  For example, `01:15` coming after `23:15`.  Is that `01:15` on the next day (2 hours later)?  If so, how would you expect to distinguish between that and `01:15` on the same day (22 hours earlier)?

Comment: It's the same day. Poke provided me with a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guild Wars 2, huh? ;P

Since each boss has at most only a single time that can be active at any moment, it is enough to just filter out those bosses that are currently running. So you don’t actually need to flatten the list to check *every* time.

So you would want to select all bosses that are currently active (with `now = DateTime.Now`):

```
bosses.Where(b => b.SpawnTimes.Where(t => t.TimeOfDay < now.TimeOfDay && now.TimeOfDay < t.TimeOfDay + b.Runtime).Count() > 0)
```

However, I personally prefer a different approach to this. Since all the bosses—except the hardcore ones—occur in a repeating cycle, it’s enough to just write down that cycle and then calculate for any given time, at which position within the cycle you are.

For that, I keep the three boss types separate, which makes the cycles extra simple (e.g. the low-level bosses are then on a cycle with only 4 different items; the standard bosses on a cycle with 6 different items). You can check my [exemplary implementation](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/index.php?title=User%3aPoke/sandbox&oldid=824252) on the official wiki, written in wiki parser code though. The idea is pretty simple though; for example for the standard bosses, this is all that’s necessary to get the current boss:

```
string[] standardBosses = new string[] { "Taidha Covington", "Megadestroyer", "The Shatterer", "Modniir Ulgoth", "Golem Mark II", "Claw of Jormag" };
Console.WriteLine(standardBosses[((int)DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 30) % 6]);
```

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense! I will be sure to check that out! :D Thank you. That IsCurrentlyActive method, do you think you could elaborate on that? :)

Comment: This is telling me (from my posted list), that "Jungle Wurm" is active , which it isn't as for ten minutes ago ^^

Comment: Are you sure you were using `DateTime.Now`? It works for me; now it reports that Tequatl is active—which is the case. And if I change `now` to match other times, it works as well. Maybe, you were testing it exactly before it switched to Behemoth at 0:45 UTC (which would fit based on your posting time - 10 minutes)?

Comment: Maybe, It's Tequatl for me now as well ^^, I'll keep monitoring it.

Comment: Depends on what you want to order it by ;D – I’d personally follow the cycle logic, where you just end up with 3 boss names (the hard one possibly empty), so you can just order them whatever you want ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56801/discussion-between-jazerix-and-poke).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you currently running bosses. Since it returns bosses, you got all the data that you need. I am not sure I understood point 1 though.

```
 bosses.Where(x => x.SpawnTimes != null && 
                   x.SpawnTimes.Count > 0 && 
                   x.SpawnTimes.Any(y => y.TimeOfDay <= DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay && 
                                         y.TimeOfDay >= DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.Subtract(x.Runtime))).ToList();
```

Beware though that your current code shifts those datetimes 2 hours +.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's relevant to you, but none of these implementation seem to handle periodicity correctly -- i.e. an event started late the previous night might still be running very early in the morning.

This should do the trick:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a time falls inside a repeating daily event of a given duration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="spawnTime">Start time of an event</param>
    /// <param name="runTime">Duration of the event</param>
    /// <param name="now">Time to test</param>
    /// <returns>true if the test time is inside the duration of the specified event.</returns>
    public static bool IsDailyEventActive(DateTime spawnTime, TimeSpan runTime, DateTime now)
    {
        // Are we inside an event that started today?
        DateTime spawnTimeToday = now.Date + spawnTime.TimeOfDay;
        if (now >= spawnTimeToday && now <= spawnTimeToday + runTime)
            return true;
        // Are we still inside an event that started yesterday?
        DateTime spawnTimeYesterday = now.Date.AddDays(-1) + spawnTime.TimeOfDay;
        if (now >= spawnTimeYesterday && now <= spawnTimeYesterday + runTime)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```